# How to transfer data between files?

Tags: excel

In one spreadsheet I have a list of emails only. In another spreadsheet I have a list of the emails but also names, organizations, etc.

I have some background in programming but not with manipulating Excel. What I would like to do in terms of pseudocode is look at each email address on a new line in the first document, test IF the second document has that email, and if so retrieve first, last name, organization, etc. from the second document, and paste it in the appropriate columns in the first column. If not, to highlight the entire row in green in the first document.

Is this possible? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do this without `VBA` using `VLOOKUP` and `Conditional Formatting`. This is also possible with `VBA` although you will need to show an attempt and some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished a couple of different ways, the easiest would be a vlookup(), but a caveat with respect to vlookup() and the arrangement of the sheet 2 Data:  Anything you would return from sheet 2 must be to the right of your lookup value (email address in your case). Vlookup() will not return anything to the left.

Also, Excel cells don't *put* into other cells, but receive a value into the current cell. (Yes, you could write a VBA function to *put* a value *into* a cell, but that may be advanced considering your experience 'manipulating Excel')

Assuming your sheet 2:

```
A             B            C
John@xyz.com  John Smith   Big Company
```

And Sheet 1:

```
A             B
John@xyz.com
```

Your psuedocode in sheet 1 would be:

vlookup(from col a, in sheet2 -columns A(1) thru C(last row), return the nth column, False - I want an exact match)

The vlookup expression is:
(again in Sheet 1 Col B -- return the company name

`=vlookup(a1,sheet2!a1:c1,3, 0)`

Here 3 refers to the 3rd column of sheet2.

If you need more information:

GOOGLE:
`vlookup()
 hlookup()
 index(match())`

Answer (score 0):

This is normally handled using the vlookup() function. So you'd use the email from book1 as the lookup_value, the range containing the values in book 2 as the table_array, the column from book 2 containing the value you want to import as the col_index_num (so if book 2 has email, name, organization in that order, you'd use 2 to pull in the name), and false as the range_lookup argument, to get an exact match. Something like

```
+VLOOKUP(A1,[Book2.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)
```

This will leave a #N/A in cells that don't have a matching email in book 2. You could use conditional formatting to turn the row green by saying "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and using =isna($b$1) as the formula for example.